# Changing the Color of the Zoom Tool Outline Rectangle in matplotlib in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Is it possible to change the color of the matplotlib 'Zoom' tool's rectangle outline in tkinter?

When using a dark stylesheet, the black outline of the zoom rectangle becomes difficult if not impossible to see; is there a way to change the color of the rectangle to make it more visible against dark backgrounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, Yes!

I wanted to share this answer since most similar answers focus on implementing this fix in Qt rather than tkinter. Here's how I achieved the desired effect...

> You'll need to override the `NavigationToolbar2Tk.draw_rubberband()` method. Here I'm using a custom class that inherits from `NavigationToolbar2Tk`, but it's not the only way:

```
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as mptk  # import the matplotlib tk backend

class CustomToolbar(mptk.NavigationToolbar2Tk):  # subclass NavigationToolbar2Tk
    def __init__(self, figcanvas, parent):
        super().__init__(figcanvas, parent)  # init the base class as usual

    # copy the method 'draw_rubberband()' right from NavigationToolbar2Tk
    # we're only changing one line
    def draw_rubberband(self, event, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        self.remove_rubberband()
        height = self.canvas.figure.bbox.height
        y0 = height - y0
        y1 = height - y1
        # this is the bit we want to change...
        self.lastrect = self.canvas._tkcanvas.create_rectangle(
            x0, y0, x1, y1
            outline = 'white'  # <- add your outline color here
        )
        # hex color strings e.g.'#BEEFED' and named colors e.g. 'gainsboro' both work
```

> You can use the `CustomToolbar` class by name just like you would use `NavigationToolbar2Tk`

```
self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self.root, self.canvas, self.frame)  # for example...
```

> Implementing a custom toolbar class that inherits from `NavigationToolbar2Tk` opens up other possibilities as well, such as modifying toolbar buttons, adding custom tools, and so on...but that's a story for another post.